# Executor Shutdown await termination not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

I am calling the await termination as i need the first two Runnables to be complete before calling the intent. However it is not working the intent is called and the when i call navEngine.getRoutes the navEngine is null.
Executor service initialised like this:

```
public static ExecutorService buildExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            navEngine = new NavigationManager(start, destination, selectedBuilding);
                        }
                    };
                    buildExecutor.execute(runnable);
                    Boolean isVisionImpaired = defaultPreferences.getString(kSightSetting, "Vision Impaired").equalsIgnoreCase("Vision Impaired");
                    if (isVisionImpaired) {
                        Runnable dRunnable = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String[] dxfs = mapManager.generateDs( new String[] { selectedBuilding.getBuildingID() });
                                navEngine.setD_for_these_buildings(dxfs);
                            }
                        };
                        buildExecutor.execute(dRunnable);
                    }

                }
                buildExecutor.shutdown();
                try {
                    buildExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDestinationActivity.this, DefineRouteActivity.class);
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Why not just do the two things in a single `Runnable`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks,  These two tasks are not quick and i need to make sure they are both complete before i can call the intent, any advice in how to ensure this would be helpful

Comment: @AndyTurner So just to check, I wish to either run the two sequentially or in parallel, however the NavEngine constructor calls other methods further down the line etc.. and both take time, so i need to ensure that both complete tasks have fully completed before i can call the intent. even if it means having to introduce a spinner to let the user know

Comment: You can run the evaluation of `navEngine` and `dxfs` in parallel if you desire; and only when you have both can you use both. (BTW, is it intentional that you don't actually use `dxfs` once evaluated?)

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner thats a typo line underneath should set Dxfs not ds. So the way  am doing it, should it work in theory is it valid? So how should i achieve this both completed before i call the intent to move to the next activity. Understanding that in the next activity i will be using the data created by these processes, so i must ensure they are complete Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I've looked a little at the possible solutions and here they are:

1. Increase await termination time
2. replace try/catch with

   ```
   while (!buildExecutor.isTerminated()); {
       //do nothing
   }
   Intent(...)
   ```
3. Create list of Callable add add here your runnables with Executors.callable and then just call invokeAll()

   ```
   List<Callable<Object>> calls = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
   calls.add(Executors.callable(your runnable here));
   buildExecutor.invokeAll(calls);
   buildExecutor.shutdown();
   Intent(...)
   ```

P.S. I am not native with concurrent, but I've tried all solutions I gave, I would also appreciate all advices)

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I do not do Android work. I am speaking to standard Java.

## Insufficient detail to reproduce the problem

The basics of your runnables and executor service are correct. Below is a simplified version of your code to show that.

So I suspect your problem lies elsewhere. You have not shown all significant parts of your code. Specifically lacking is the definition of `navEngine` which seems to be the root of your complaint.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "`demo` method ending. " + Instant.now() );
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );

        // Navigation Manager work.
        Runnable navManTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ( )
            {
                System.out.println( "navManTask - beginning. Will sleep to simulate lengthy work. " + Instant.now() );
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    System.out.println( "navManTask - sleep interrupted. Ending this task prematurely. " + Instant.now() );
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println( "navManTask - ending. " + Instant.now() );
            }
        };
        executorService.execute( navManTask );

        // Vision Impaired work.
        boolean isVisionImpaired = true;
        if ( isVisionImpaired )
        {
            Runnable visionTask = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run ( )
                {
                    System.out.println( "visionTask - beginning. Will sleep to simulate lengthy work. " + Instant.now() );
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() );
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e )
                    {
                        System.out.println( "visionTask - sleep interrupted. Ending this task prematurely. " + Instant.now() );
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println( "visionTask - ending. " + Instant.now() );
                }
            };
            executorService.execute( visionTask );

            System.out.println( "`demo` method asking  executor service to shut down. " + Instant.now() );
            executorService.shutdown();
            try
            {
                System.out.println( "`main` method waiting for the executor service to shut down. " + Instant.now() );
                executorService.awaitTermination( 30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println( "`demo` method ending. " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }
}
```

### Other issues

You likely have other concurrency problems.

#### Contention over accessing the `navEngine` object via two threads

You have two simultaneous threads accessing the same resource, that variable `navEngine`. Two problems there: visibility and thread-safety.

Visibility under the Java Memory Model is where a primitive or object reference accessed across threads may show two different cached values. One solution to this is the `volatile` keyword. Another solution may be the [`Atomic…`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) class. Search to learn more about the visibility issue.

We do not see the class behind that `navEngine`. But that class must be made to be thread-safe if an object of that class may be manipulated across threads.

#### Second thread depends on the first

In the code of one thread you are instantiating an object to place in the `navEngine` variable. In the code of the other thread, you assume that object exists. But you cannot predict in what order the threads will do their work. The scheduling of threads is effectively arbitrary and unpredictable, depending on the momentary conditions and the CPU scheduling decision-making policies of both the host OS and the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). It is entirely possible that the second thread will try to access `navEngine` *before* the first thread has populated the variable with an object reference.

Since the second runnable depends on the first being complete and successful, there is no point to you having two separate threads. You might as well combine the two into a single `Runnable` task.

If you insist on the two threads, then you will need to change your calls to `execute` to `submit`. The `submit` method returns a `Future` object. You can use this `Future` object to check on the success of the first task.

Here is the above code revised to capture the `Future` returned when submitting the navMan task to the executor service. The vision work waits for that `Future` to signal that the navMan work is done.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "`demo` method ending. " + Instant.now() );
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );

        // Navigation Manager work.
        Runnable navManTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ( )
            {
                System.out.println( "navManTask - beginning. Will sleep to simulate lengthy work. " + Instant.now() );
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    System.out.println( "navManTask - sleep interrupted. Ending this task prematurely. " + Instant.now() );
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println( "navManTask - ending. " + Instant.now() );
            }
        };
        Future < String > navManFuture = executorService.submit( navManTask , "whatever" );

        // Vision Impaired work.
        boolean isVisionImpaired = true;
        if ( isVisionImpaired )
        {
            Runnable visionTask = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run ( )
                {
                    System.out.println( "visionTask - beginning. Will sleep to simulate lengthy work. " + Instant.now() );
                    if ( navManFuture.isCancelled() )
                    {
                        System.out.println( "visionTask - Found the navMan task got cancelled. Ending this task prematurely. " + Instant.now() );
                        return;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println( "visionTask - Waiting for the navMan task to be done. " + Instant.now() );
                        String whatever = navManFuture.get(); // Wait for `namManTask` to get done. This code blocks here, waiting.
                        Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ).toMillis() );
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e )
                    {
                        System.out.println( "visionTask - sleep interrupted. Ending this task prematurely. " + Instant.now() );
                        return;
                    }
                    catch ( ExecutionException e )
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "visionTask - ending. " + Instant.now() );
                }
            };
            executorService.submit( visionTask );

            System.out.println( "`demo` method asking  executor service to shut down. " + Instant.now() );
            executorService.shutdown();
            try
            {
                System.out.println( "`main` method waiting for the executor service to shut down. " + Instant.now() );
                executorService.awaitTermination( 30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println( "`demo` method ending. " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }
}
```

## Project Loom

By the way, if and when [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology arrives in Java, the code seen here will be simpler. In Loom, the `ExecutorService` interface is also [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). This means we can use convenient try-with-resources syntax. The `close` method blocks until all submitted tasks are done/failed/canceled.